# JQuery - Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocate is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Trying to use the Google Address auto-complete API.  My page loads fine however when initiating a search it doesn't return anything.  When I Inspect Element I get the following error [Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocate is not defined]. I've searched resources on SOF and have tried the following:

- I'v moved my script to the bottom of the page
- I've Added the  $(document).ready(function ()
- Declared all my var globally
- Verified all referenced id's exists

I would really appreciate so help.  This has me pulling out what little hair I have left. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeFile="tet.aspx.cs" Inherits="tet" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <%--   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>--%>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="autocomplete" CssClass="form-control input-lg" runat="server" onFocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Enter your address..."></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="street_number" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="route" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    Address:
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_AddressLine1" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    City:
<asp:TextBox ID="locality" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    State:
<asp:TextBox ID="administrative_area_level_1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Postal Code:
<asp:TextBox ID="postal_code" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Country:
<asp:TextBox ID="country" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<br />
</asp:Panel>
```

--%>

```
     <script>
         // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
         // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var geolocation
             var val
             var addressType
             var component
             var place
         var placeSearch, autocomplete;
         var componentForm = {
             street_number: 'short_name',
             route: 'long_name',
             locality: 'long_name',
             administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
             country: 'long_name',
             postal_code: 'short_name'
         };

         function initialize() {
         // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
         // to geographical location types.
         autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
         /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
         { types: ['geocode'] });
         // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
         // populate the address fields in the form.
         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
         fillInAddress();
             });
         }

         // [START region_fillform]
         function fillInAddress() {
         // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
         place = autocomplete.getPlace();

         for ( component in componentForm) {
         document.getElementById(component).value = '';
         document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
           }


         $("#tb_AddressLine1").val(place.address_components[0][componentForm["street_number"]] + " " +
         place.address_components[1][componentForm["route"]]);

         // Get each component of the address from the place details
         // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
         for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
         addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
         if (componentForm[addressType]) {
         val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
         document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;

                 }
             }
         }
         // [END region_fillform]

         // [START region_geolocation]
         // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
         // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
         function geolocate() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
         geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
         position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
         autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
         geolocation));
                 });
             }
         }
         // [END region_geolocation]
         });
```

```
</div</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Answer added, hopefully this is will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... I forgot to add ClientIDMode="Static" to all TextBoxes, so when the page is loaded the JavaScript doesn't "see" the fields it is looking for.
Added that and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this on focus of the textbox, you can just activate it by calling `geolocate()` after having initialized the searchbox.  This will surely work.

I mistakenly assumed that you were using a Google Map originally.

Comment: I figured it out... I forgot to add ClientIDMode="Static" to all  TextBoxes.  Thanks for the help though.